# "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad" with JNI call from java to .so

Tags: java-native-interface

I use my own .so library to build an Android App. It goes well last night. But it comes to this err: **A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1) ** this morning when I Debug it. This is my .so code:

```
config_t config_obj_ptr = NULL;
module_t module_ptr = NULL;
int module_interface_init(const char * path)
{
    LOGD("==========wrapper init==========\n");
if(path == NULL)
{
    LOGD("path is not available");
    return -1;
}
const char * app_path = path;
const char * cache_path = app_path;
config_obj_ptr = lib_create_config();
    LOGD("Mark===1!\n");
if(NULL == config_obj_ptr)
{
    LOGD("create config object err!\n");
    getchar();
    return -1;
}
set_app_path(config_obj_ptr, app_path);
set_cache_path(config_obj_ptr, cache_path);
    LOGD("Mark===2!\n");
module_ptr = create_module(config_obj_ptr);
    LOGD("Mark===3!\n");
if(NULL == p2p_module_ptr)
{
    LOGD("create p2p module err!");
    getchar();
    return -1;
    }

return 0;
}
```

I call this method through JNI in java :

```
private wrapper(String path)
{
    nInit(path);
}
```

I find that crash occurred in this function (from my .so): I can get Log to "Mark===2!", no "Mark===3!". so it must be **module_ptr = create_module(config_obj_ptr);** cause this problem. config_obj_ptr  and module_ptr are all  global variable declared outside the function. config_obj_ptr  can work well but module_ptr can't.

Comment: Try getting a stack trace.  It will help us figure out why create_module is causing a segfault.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But I can't get this crash any more. I just plug the phone into another computer and debug it, succeed. Then turn back to my computer, succeed too! I can't say a word。。。

Comment: It could have been a problem somewhere else like the module you are trying to load.  If it does come back, get that stack trace or check the message logs for clues.  Good Luck ;)